# Cisco 3620, installing nm-2fe2w

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, cisco-ios-12

Is the WIC plug and play or are there commands that I need to run? The router is not showing the interfaces. I tried using the sh diag and it didn't show anything.

Comment: you cannot insert a 3600 intf with power on... did you reboot?  If that doesnt work check ios support... on cell I cant check now

Comment: The power is off when I've tried to install the card, reboot didn't work. I will get the current IOS of it

Comment: I would check the release notes for your current IOS to see if it is already supported.... also make sure screws are tight on the card

Comment: Just confirmed its not compatible with the IOS, router is on 11.x and it needs to be 12.x. No way to update IOS with the fa ports?

Comment: of course you can use any interface you like to upgrade... all you need is IP connectivity to a tftp, or ftp server... alternatively, get a PCMCIA from another 3600 and sneakernet it.  All this is from crusty middle age memory while I type at red lights... apologies if there is no PCMCIA slot but I seem to remember it having one.

Comment: The 3620 has 2x PCMCIA slots, luckily I have a card, I'll look up how to sneakernet it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're running IOS 11, but you need one of these (or higher) for the nm-2fe2w card to work...

- 12.0(7)XK
- 12.1(1)T
- 12.1(5)YB
- 12.2(1)
- 12.2(2)T

If you have enough DRAM / Flash, I would go with the latest 12.2 for the Cisco3620... that's 12.2(26c)GD...

FYI, the `c3620-d-mz.122-26c.bin` image will fit on 32M DRAM and 8M flash... avoid 12.2T if possible.  As we discussed in comments, load it on a PCMCIA with another 3600 and sneakernet.